# Tensorflow Embedding Layer Vocabulary Size

Tags: python, tensorflow, word-embedding

I am learning Tensorflow and have come across the Embedding layer in tensorflow used to learn one's own word embeddings. The layer takes the following parameters:

```
keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, 
                       output_dim, 
                       embeddings_initializer='uniform',
                       embeddings_regularizer=None, 
                       activity_regularizer=None, 
                       embeddings_constraint=None, 
                       mask_zero=False, 
                       input_length=None)
```

The 'input dim' should be the same size as the vocabulary i.e. unique words. If I wanted to limit the vocabulary to only the first 25000 most frequent words - how should I do this?

Can I simply change 'input_dim' to 25000 or would I have to go through my corpus and replace any word that is outside the top 25000 words with an  token for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, if you use `tensorflow.keras` you have to make sure in your corpus, the tokens don't exceed the vocabulary_size or the `input_dim` of embedding layer, otherwise you'll get error.

If you use `keras`, then you can just change the `input_dim` in your embedding layer without changing anything in corpus or tokens. `keras` will replace out of vocabulary tokens with a `zero` vector.

First of all, there is an error if you use tensorflow.keras.

**tensorflow**

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Input
import numpy as np

ip = Input(shape = (3,))
emb = Embedding(1, 2, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)(ip)

model = Model(ip, emb)
input_array = np.array([[5, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]]) # out of vocabulary

model.compile("rmsprop", "mse")

output_array = model.predict(input_array)

print(output_array)

print(output_array.shape)

model.summary()
```

[image]

But if I use keras 2.3.1, I don't get any error.

**keras 2.3.1**

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
import numpy as np

ip = Input(shape = (3,))
emb = Embedding(1, 2, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)(ip)

model = Model(ip, emb)
input_array = np.array([[5, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]])

model.compile("rmsprop", "mse")

output_array = model.predict(input_array)

print(output_array)

print(output_array.shape)

model.summary()
```

[image]

keras has different implementations for embedding layer. To validate that, let's go to keras embedding layer.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/embeddings.py#L16

For now let's just look into call function.

```
    def call(self, inputs):
        if K.dtype(inputs) != 'int32':
            inputs = K.cast(inputs, 'int32')
        out = K.gather(self.embeddings, inputs)
        return out
```

N.B: If you want the exact source code for keras 2.3.1 go here and download source code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases

But if we go to tensorflow implementation, it's different.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/embedding_ops.py

Just to verify, the call function is differently written.

```
  def call(self, inputs):
    dtype = K.dtype(inputs)
    if dtype != 'int32' and dtype != 'int64':
      inputs = math_ops.cast(inputs, 'int32')
    out = embedding_ops.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings, inputs)
    return out
```

Let's design a simple network like before and observe the weight matrix.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
import numpy as np

ip = Input(shape = (3,))
emb = Embedding(1, 2, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)(ip)

model = Model(ip, emb)
input_array = np.array([[5, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]])

model.compile("rmsprop", "mse")

output_array = model.predict(input_array)

print(output_array)

print(output_array.shape)

model.summary()
```

The model gives the following output.

```
[[[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]
  [0. 0.]]]
(2, 3, 2)
Model: "model_18"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_21 (InputLayer)        (None, 3)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_33 (Embedding)     (None, 3, 2)              2         
=================================================================
Total params: 2
Trainable params: 2
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Okay, we are getting bunch of zeros but the default weight_initializer is not zeros!

So, let's observe the weight matrix now.

```
import keras.backend as K

w = model.layers[1].get_weights()
print(w)
```

```
[array([[ 0.03680499, -0.04904002]], dtype=float32)]
```

In fact, it is not all zeros.

So, why are we getting zeros?

Let's change our input to the model.

As the only in vocabulary word index for input_dim = 1, is 0. Let's pass 0 as one of the inputs.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input
import numpy as np

ip = Input(shape = (3,))
emb = Embedding(1, 2, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)(ip)

model = Model(ip, emb)
input_array = np.array([[5, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]])

model.compile("rmsprop", "mse")

output_array = model.predict(input_array)

print(output_array)

print(output_array.shape)

model.summary()
```

Now, we get non-zero vectors for the positions where we passed 0.

```
[[[ 0.          0.        ]
  [-0.04339869 -0.04900574]
  [ 0.          0.        ]]

 [[ 0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.        ]
  [-0.04339869 -0.04900574]]]
(2, 3, 2)
Model: "model_19"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_22 (InputLayer)        (None, 3)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_34 (Embedding)     (None, 3, 2)              2         
=================================================================
Total params: 2
Trainable params: 2
Non-trainable params: 0
```

In short, Keras maps any out of vocabulary word index with a zero vector and this is reasonable as for those positions the forward pass will ensure all the contributions are NIL (the biases may have a role though). That is a little bit counter-intuitive as passing out of vocabulary tokens to the model seems an overhead (rather than just removing them in the pre-processing step) and bad practice but it is a good fix to test different `input_dim` without re-calculating tokens.

Comment: Zabir, thank you so much - this is super helpful! I appreciate such a comprehensive answer. Is there a reason why tensorflow.keras and keras are so different?

Comment: they are not so different, but definitely tensorflow.keras is better maintained. `keras` has different implementations in many cases so there is some inconsistencies even though syntax is almost same.

Comment: Thanks, Zabir. Could I also use the TensorFlow Tokenizer class to preprocess the text, and set the 'num_words' (25000 in the example above) with an OOV_token??

Comment: yes, if you use `keras` instead of `tensorflow.keras`